# How to connect a Chat Client to a game server?

Tags: c#

I just want to create a "Chat Client" that can connect to a Game Server..

My problem is that I dont know how to start, I've already read several tutorials about socket programming / chat client / server client / etc. but I can't find a way to implement it on a game  server.

The server I want to connect is a Battle.net server "Warcraft III".

I've already know the IP Adress of the server but I dont know how will I able to access the game server.
The IP address of the server serves as a Webserver "acts a forum" and a GameServer "of course the game itself".

to summarize my problem:
I just want to create my own "Topaz Chat" using C# but I dont have any idea how to do it?

any idea? guys even a keyword is enough, I will try my best to find a tutorial for it. I know its hard to answer my question because I failed to provide any code T_T

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you need to find out the protocol that the chat uses. Try to find answers to these questions:

- Do you really need raw sockets?
- Is the protocol a know protocol, such as IRC?
- What are the chat's commands and how are they processed?

When you find these answers, you'll be half way there.

Comment: oppss, I forgot to include this on my question: Since I want to create a chat client and connect to a game server, I need to put my username and password to my chat client and let it access my acount on the server side. any idea how to do it? Btw, thanks for the fast reply guys, I really appeciate it......

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you can access the Battle.net to get some informations, then I believe it uses a WEB SERVICE. Using it, you can request some informations or to create a room or something. You should not use socket programming. WCF is a highter level technology of .NET. Use it as web service.

Comment: oppss, I forgot to include this on my question: Since I want to create a chat client and connect to a game server, I need to put my username and password to my chat client and let it access my acount on the server side. any idea how to do it? Btw, thanks for the fast reply guys, I really appeciate it......

Comment: I think you should have more experience developing. In my opinion, you should try to do a WCF simple example. Then you may understand.